# Processing a byte string in chunks

Tags: python, numpy, chunks

I have a really long byte string such as this (the actual value may be random):

```py
in_var = b'\x01\x02\x03\x04\x05\x06...\xff'
```

I also have a function that performs an operation on a chunk of bytes and returns the same number of bytes (let's say 10 bytes for this example):

```py
def foo(chunk):
  # do smth with chunk
  # ......
  return chunk
```

I want to process `in_var` with `foo()` for all chunks of 10 bytes (sending the last chunk as is if less than 10 bytes remain at the end) and create a new variable `out_var` with the outputs.

The way I'm currently doing it is taking way too long:

```py
out_var = b''
for chunk in range(0, len(in_var), 10):
    out_var += foo(in_var[chunk: chunk + 10])
```

The function `foo()` only takes a fraction of a second per run, so the total should be very fast (total of all chunks of 10). However, I'm getting an order of magnitude longer.

I also tried this with similar results:

```py
import numpy as np
import math
in_var= np.array_split(np.frombuffer(in_var, dtype=np.uint8), math.ceil(len(in_var)/10))
out_var= b"".join(map(lambda x: foo(x), in_var))
```

`foo()` can only process 10 bytes for this example (ex: it's an encryption function with a fixed block size) and if a smaller chunk is given to it, it just pads to make the chunk 10 bytes. Let's say I have no control over it, and `foo()` can only process in chunks of 10 bytes.

Is there a much faster way to do this? As a last resort, I may have to parallelize my code so all chunks get processed in parallel...

Thank you!

---

UPDATE:

Apparently I had not correctly measured the time `foo()` takes. It turns out, `foo()` is taking the majority of the time, hence the order of magnitude comment above. Thank you again for your comments and suggestions, I did make some improvements nevertheless. Parallelizing the code seems to be the correct path forward.

Comment: `out_var += foo(in_var[chunk: chunk + 10])` Repeated string concatenation is very slow.

Comment: Why deliberately sabotage performance by calling a function on only 10 bytes at a time when you could do much larger chunks?  The naive solution is so much faster than your complicated one, and I have to imagine you have already thought of some reason you can't use the fast naive solution, but you haven't told us.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Let's say I have no control over foo(), it only processes 10 bytes at a time. I have edited my question to make that clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your `for` loop is that it creates a new string, slightly longer each time, and copies the old data to the new.  You can speed it up by pre-allocating the bytes and just copying over them directly:

```
out_var = bytearray(len(in_var))
for chunk in range(0, len(in_var), 10):
    out_var[chunk: chunk + 10] = foo(in_var[chunk: chunk + 10])
```

Comment: Two errors with this: 1. `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for //: 'bytes' and 'int'` and 2. `TypeError: 'bytes' object does not support item assignment`. The first is fixed by adding () around the first multiplication: `out_var = b' ' *(len(in_var) // 10 * 10)`

Comment: @ItM: You're right, edited.  Please try it now.

Comment: I updated the post. Thank you for all your help anyways!